# How to watch or read new log files with Logstash?

Tags: logging, logstash, elastic-stack, logstash-configuration

EDIT: Trying to watch Magento report logs. Magento writes its crash report to a new file everytime an exception occurs.

According to Logstash oficial documentation: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-file.html
the option dicover_interval means "How often (in seconds) we expand the filename patterns in the path option to discover **new files** to watch."

**The problem**: I have a system that writes its logs on a new file every time a new exception occurs (The file name is the exception number). However, Logstash on startup, starts watching the existing files , but I cant get Logstash to read the new files.

My conf file:

```
    input {
      file {
        type => "error-report-log"
        path => "/srv/www/var/report"
        #start_position => "beginning"
        ignore_older => 30
        close_older => 30
        discover_interval => 5
        codec => multiline {
            pattern => "."
            what => "previous"
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, I've tried discover_interval with no luck. New files are not getting watched.

Am I missing something or Logstash simply does not support this kind of behavior ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you're missing out the [sincedb_path](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-file.html#plugins-inputs-file-sincedb_path) within your `file`. What if you have your input as such:

```
input {
  file {
    type => "error-report-log"
    path => "/srv/www/var/report"
    sincedb_path => "/dev/null"   <-- add this line
    start_position => "beginning" <-- uncomment this
    ignore_older => 0             <-- change it to zero
    codec => multiline {
        pattern => "."
        what => "previous"
    }
}
```

Once you have it, logstash should pick up any new lines or new files which are being added.

Comment: Thanks @Darth_Vader. You got close but new files get read only if logstash is restarted. I also tried  discover_interval => 1 ignore_older => 0/1 with no luck, logstash is definatley not picking up new filesunless you restart it.

Any Ideas ?

Comment: So you mean, when `logstash` is up and running, when you add a new file in the file path, it doesn't get picked up? You sure that you've given a pattern to your file path instead of the file name, so that it can read new files?

Comment: Correct. Its not picking up or watching new files, and logstash is up a running. Tried versions 5 and 5.1. Im sure that Im specifing a path. I've tried the following paths: /srv/www/var/report and /srv/www/var/report/* . What could be wrong ?

Comment: **/srv/www/var/report/*** means that all the newly added files should be picked up in the path.

Answer (score 1):

SOLUTION: Using **Filebeat** and pass the logs through Logstash is a much better approach :

```
filebeat:
  prospectors:
    -
      input_type: log
      scan_frequency: 5s
      paths:
        - /srv/www/var/report/*
      fields:
        app_id: "${APP_ID}"
        type: error-report-log
      multiline:
        pattern: '^\$'
        negate: true
        match: after
output:
  logstash:
    enabled: true
    hosts: ["my.logstash.com:5044"]
```

This solution has been tested with **Magento 2**.

Magento 2 writes its exception / crash report to a new file everytime.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @kaßta for template!

I improved it a bit so file is not picked up again and again with `ignore_older` together with `scan_frequency`. Also `close_eof` will keep processing resources to minimum.

```
filebeat.prospectors:
  - input_type: log
    close_eof: true
    ignore_older: 1m
    scan_frequency: 1m
    paths:
      - "/srv/www/var/report/*"
    fields:
      project: shop
      app: magento
      env: development
    multiline:
      pattern: '^\$'
      negate: true
      match: after

output.logstash:
  hosts: ['logstash:5044']
```